# Can't access user in comment object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following models, Post, Comment, and User. The Comment object belongs to user, and the user has many comments. However, when trying to render a view to show the comments, the user can't be accessed and shows undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass. The avatar attached is a method associated with the User class.

This is the comments controller

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :set_commentable 

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
        @comment.user = current_user
        @comment.save
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment Posted!"
    end

    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments.all
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
    end



    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
        end

        def set_commentable
            @commentable = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        end

end
```

Here is the Comment model:

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Here is the User model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  acts_as_voter

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_one_attached :avatar


  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

end
```

Here is the view I am trying to render. I want the comments to be displayed at the bottom of the show view for a post:

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round m7" style="margin:auto; display:table; min-width: 500px; max-width: 800px;"><br>
        <% if @post.user.avatar.attached? %>
            <%= image_tag @post.user.avatar, class: "w3-circle avatar w3-left w3-margin-right", :style => "display: inline;" %>
        <% else %>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to @post do %>
        <span class="w3-right w3-opacity"><%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago</span>
        <% end %>

        <h4><%= @post.user.name %></h4> <h5>@<%= @post.user.username%></h5>
        <hr class="w3-clear">
        <p><%= @post.content %></p>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <hr class="w3-clear">
        <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put,  class: "w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom" do%>
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            <span class="w3-badgeM"><%= @post.get_upvotes.size %></span>
        <% end %>    
        <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></button>

        <% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
            <%= link_to edit_post_path(@post), class: "w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom" do %>
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to @post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this post?"}, class: "w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom" do %>
                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% else %>
        <br >
        <% end %>

        <%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
            <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: 'textarea' }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class: 'label' }  %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Leave a reply', class: "button is-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <% @post.comments.each do |comment|%>
        <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-round w3-margin" style="background-color: #f3f3f3; padding: 0px 5px 5px;" ><br>
            <% if comment.user.avatar.attached? %>
                <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar, class: "w3-circle avatar w3-left w3-margin-right", :style => "display: inline;" %>
            <% else %>
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
            <% end %>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>

            <% end %>
            <span class="w3-right w3-opacity"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
            <h6><%= comment.user.name %></h6> <p><strong>@<%= comment.user.username%></strong></p>
            <p style="max-height: 75px; overflow:auto;"><%= comment.body %></p>

        </div>
        <% end %>

    </div>
```

The routes.rb file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #  :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like" => "posts#upvote"
      put "unlike" => "posts#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end   
  root "posts#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

However, when I try to render this, I get the following error:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/HV3qkr7/error.jpg]

If I look in the database, the comment record exists with the correct ids:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/FXvPpSF/db.jpg]

When I try to run the avatar attached method in the console after selecting the post, it seems to return true and not throw any errors:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/X3k3mBq/console.jpg]

Could someone help me out, and point out where I went wrong?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a simple fix! I just had to wrap the comments view inside `<% if !comment.user.nil? %>` For some reason, the first comment does not seem to have a user associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your post doesn't have a user associated with it. It's hard to see as your error message is so far zoomed out, but line 3 of your code:

```
<% if @post.user.avatar.attached? %>
```

Is where the error is occuring. It's not occuring because the user does not have an avatar, but because you're trying to find the avatar of nilclass.

Your two options are to fix the @post in question so it's associated with a user (you can dot his from console), or to change the line to:

```
<% if @post.user&.avatar.attached? %>
```

This will stop execution if the post's user is nil, and simply return false rather than blowing up. If however your post is supposed to have a user attached, then I'd suggest fixing this rather than changing your logic to account for posts without users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The error occurs with the comment.user.avatar.attached? line much further down. You can see the pictures more clearly by right click, and then open image in a new tab/view image ...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: There is no instance variable like `@post`, so I would start with that :)

Secondly: I would suggest wrapping everything into objects implementing a Presenter design pattern. I would separate the presentation layer from business/persistence layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure what you mean by class variable @post. Could you explain this further?

Comment: @Ganesh - I made a mistake with that one! I meant "instance" variable. An attribute of an object. As you can see, you are asking in that view about something that does not exist in your Controller. There is no declaration of `@post`.

Comment: @Micheal - The `@post` does not seem to throw an issue, as this is rendering the "show" view for the posts. The `@post` seems to reference the current post correctly. However, the comments in `@post`.comments do not seem to be able to access their "belongs-to" user.

Comment: @Ganesh - It won't throw an error because when you ask for `@post`, you will get a `nil`, not an error. You are not setting it anywhere. Try to change `@post` reference to `@commentable`.

Comment: @Ganesh could you attach your `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: @Micheal - Sure! `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #  :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like" => "posts#upvote"
      put "unlike" => "posts#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end   
  root "posts#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
` It's also on the main post

Comment: @Ganesh - thank you! I checked and everything seems fine with your routes. Could you please try to what I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @Micheal -Where would you like me to update the post reference to commentable?

Comment: @Micheal - For all occurences, or just where I am rendering the comments?

Comment: @Ganesh - all occurrences

Comment: @Micheal - Here is the result: https://i.ibb.co/6WpvmxJ/se1.jpg . It still cannot get the class